# Problem returning values from a Ray.remote parallel Python 3 function

Tags: amazon-ec2, parallel-processing, remote-access, ray

I have been working on an EC2 parallel cloud application using Ray for setting up the cluster and scheduling the tasks. However, I have a problem that has been perplexing me.  The following is a very simplified program (running on 3 workers) that illustrates it:-

```
import numpy as np
import subprocess as sp
import boto3
import ray

redadd=sp.check_output("hostname -I",shell=True).decode("utf-8").rstrip()
ray.init(redis_address=redadd+":6379")
pop=np.ones((3,3))

@ray.remote
def test_loop(n):                                           
    return n*pop[n,:]

for i in range(0,2): 
    print("iteration ",i)
    print(pop)
    if __name__=='__main__':
        ans=ray.get([test_loop.remote(n) for n in range(0,3)])
    print("ans ",ans)
    pop=2*pop

ray.shutdown()
```

The output of this is:-

```
2019-07-03 23:35:06,078 WARNING worker.py:1337 -- WARNING: Not updating   worker name since `setproctitle` is not installed. Install this with `pip install setproctitle` (or ray[debug]) to enable monitoring of worker processes.
iteration  0
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
ans  [array([0., 0., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1.]), array([2., 2., 2.])]
iteration  1
[[2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2.]
 [2. 2. 2.]]
ans  [array([0., 0., 0.]), array([1., 1., 1.]), array([2., 2., 2.])]
```

Ignoring the warning, the puzzle is that the value of pop is read during the first iteration of the test_loop, returning the three product vectors in parallel.  However, on the next iteration, where pop's value has been doubled, the test_loop ignores it and retains the old value. Can anyone explain what is going on here, and how to get the remote function call to work as I would expect?

N.B. I don't think that this is a scope problem: pop is globally defined and is not re-assigned in test_loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Ray "worker" runs in a separate process (as opposed to a thread), so there aren't any globally scoped variables that are shared between all of the workers.

When you define the `test_loop` remote function, the function definition is serialized and shipped to each worker process (along with the `pop` array). So each worker process (in addition to your main script) has its own copy of `pop`. When you modify `pop` in the main script, that doesn't affect the other copies of the `pop` array.

If you want your worker processes to have state that gets mutated when methods run, you may want to use [Ray actors](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actors.html).

Comment: I see, thanks.  Do you think that the Ray actor approach is preferable to passing pop as an argument to test_loop?

Comment: Passing `pop` as an argument into `test_loop` should work nicely.

Comment: That did work, but not nicely: I get an error from some pyarrow method if pop is too large.  I will post the issue as a separate question.